# Checking if search query is for boolean mode

Tags: mysql, booleanquery

How should I check that a query is supposed to be for a MySQL Boolean Mode FULLTEXT search instead of a NATURAL MODE search? Detecting special character operators such as +, - using regex or something else?

Comment: You may want to add more details to your question.

Comment: You could check the query itself to see how you coded it :p